# How to make rounded corner image or circular image

Tags: javascript, css, image

I have some images and I want to show them on my webpage. But the problem is that I want to make their corners rounded. The deepness of rounded corner depends, some time I want decent  round corners and some time I want very deep round corners so that it appear a circular image. 
What is right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following css:

```
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
```

Note:- This will not work in IE except IE9.

Comment: Actually, IE 9 supports border-radius.

Comment: @Emil: Yes it does. but peoples has not started to use IE9 especially with windows XP. Updated answer.

Comment: @Harry: IE is  very popular , so we can't leave it. have you any other solution (IE compatible).

Comment: @jams: for IE use [Curvy Corner](http://code.google.com/p/curvycorners/). It's javascript solution. Also see this discussion: http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers

Comment: @Harry:All these are talking about round corners, but what about circular image?

Comment: @jams: give large number in radius and it will become circle

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Gecko browsers */
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
/* Webkit browsers */
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
/* W3C syntax - likely to be standard so use for future proofing */
border-radius: 5px;
```

Use all 3 to ensure the most compatibility. IE7 and IE8 don't support border-radius except IE9. However There are JavaScript hacks, most involve a heap of 1px elements absolutely positioned or use SVG.

Comment: IE is  very popular , so we can't leave it. have you any other solution (IE compatible).

Answer (score 1):

Rounded corners are not supported by some major browsers (ok maybe one major browser which is ... yes IE). The only way to get a cross browser solution is to use a jQuery plugin to round the corners.

[Tutorial on rounded corners](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aRounded_Corners)

Answer (score 1):

Go here

Here automatically generates all browser specific CSS

### http://css3generator.com/

or

### http://css3please.com/